# Filter out empty <span> tags from html code

Tags: python, html, regex, filter

I have some html code where there's a lot of lines that I want to remove that look like this

```
<span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:94px; top:600px; width:6px; height:10px;"></span>
```

Now there are also span tags that have text in between them and I want to keep.

I want to use the python re.sub function to delete those useless span tags. I wrote this but it is not working

```
html_code_filtered = re.sub('<span*></span>', '', html_code)
```

I guess I'm missing something on the regular expression to match the lines correctly?

Comment: use beautifullsoup if possible for this kind of issues see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: What happens when a span tag contains for example only an img tag?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte In this case it wouldn't be deleted but I don't have to deal with something like that because that won't happen in the html files I'm processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an HTML Parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to remove the `span` elements with no text.

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:94px; top:600px; width:6px; height:10px;"></span>
    <span>useful text</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

# find and remove "span" elements with empty contents
for useless in soup.find_all("span", text=lambda text: not text):
    useless.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints (as you can see `span` elements with no contents were removed):

```
<div>
 <span>
  useful text
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `n*` looks for the character n repeated zero or more times. You can use `.*?` to match all characters until the next > character.

```
>>> html_code = '<span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:94px; top:600px; width:6px; height:10px;"></span>' 
>>> re.sub('<span.*?></span>', '', html_code)
''
```

That being said, refer to maazaa's comment and the answers using a proper html parser for more complex parsing tasks.